# Hibernate One-to-many HashMap not updating on child

Tags: java, hibernate, orm

I have the following parent object which maps to a table in my database:

```
public Parent {
    private Long id;
    private String mid;
    private Integer days;
    private BigDecimal fee;
    private DateTime createdDate = new DateTime();
    private DateTime lastModifiedDate;

    private Map<String, Child> children;
}
```

With the following .hbm.xml:

```
    <hibernate-mapping default-access="field">
    <class name="Parent" table="parent_table">
        <id column="id" length="50" name="id" unsaved-value="null">
            <generator class="increment"/>
        </id>
        <property length="50" name="mid"/>
        <property name="days"/>
        <property name="fee"/>
        <property name="createdDate" type="(...)PersistentDateTime"/>
        <property name="lastModifiedDate" type="(...)PersistentDateTime"/>
        <map cascade="all-delete-orphan" inverse="true" name="children" >
            <key column="parentId" />
            <map-key column="country" type="string" />
            <one-to-many class="Child" />
        </map>
    </class>
    </hibernate-mapping>
```

The child object is as follows:

```
public class Child implements Serializable {
    private Long parentId;
    private String country;
    private String cu;
}
```

With the following .hbm.xml:

```
<hibernate-mapping default-access="field">
<class name="Child" table="child_table">
    <composite-id>
        <key-property name="parentId"/>
        <key-property name="country"/>
        <key-property name="cu"/>
    </composite-id>
</class>
</hibernate-mapping>
```

After acquiring a Parent object from my db via:

```
getSession().createCriteria(Parent.class)
                            .add(Restrictions.eq("mid", mid))
                            .uniqueResult();
```

After making some changes to Child.cu in the children map I call a saveOrUpdate on the Parent object. After doing so all appears to save / update fine but upon checking the child_table in the db, these changes have not been saved / updated.

I believe this has something to do with the mappings of the map in the Parent class but can't seem to figure it out. Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand correctly, you're modifying a field which is part of the primary key of your entity. This is illegal: the ID should be immutable.

My advice is to follow the good practices: use a non-composite, purely technical, auto-generated primary key. Everything will be much simpler (and also faster).